# Dash four callbacks with same input and different outputs

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

To pass data from the dropdown to all other different callbacks using dcc.store, where I'm storing the selected value from the dropdown in dcc.store.

Tried to store the selected data from the dropdown using dcc.store and pass the data to all other callbacks. One callback is to generate dynamic tabs and another callback(render_graph) is to generate a graph based on tab selection and another callback(render_table) is to generate another data table and another callback(render__checklist_graph) is to generate a graph based on checkbox selection, but getting the error as Error loading dependencies.

```
import psycopg2 as pg
import pandas.io.sql as psql
import pandas as pd
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table as dt
import plotly.graph_objs as go


conn = pg.connect(database="db",user="user", password="password")

df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * from "table"', conn)

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div([dcc.Store(id='memory-output')]),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='my-dropdown', options=[#dropdown
        {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df.number.unique()
    ], multi=False, placeholder='Select Number...'),
    html.Div(id='output-container'),#dynamic tabs
    html.Div([# dynamic graph1 based on tab selection
        dcc.Graph(id='graph', figure={'layout':{'xaxis':{'showgrid':False,'zeroline':False,'showticklabels':False},'yaxis':{'showgrid':False,'zeroline':False,'showticklabels':False}}})]),#plot
    html.Div([#table
        dt.DataTable(id='data-table')
    ]),
    html.Div([# dynamic checkbox
        html.H5('Multiple Graphs'),
        dcc.Checklist(id='checklist', values=[])]),#checklist
    html.Div([#dynamic graph2 based on checkbox selection
        dcc.Graph(id='checklist-graph', figure={'layout':{'xaxis':{'showgrid':False,'zeroline':False,'showticklabels':False},'yaxis':{'showgrid':False,'zeroline':False,'showticklabels':False}}})])#plot
])

app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions'] = True

@app.callback([Output('output-container', 'children'),
              Output('checklist','options'),
              Output('memory-output', 'data')],
              [Input('my-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_output(value):
    number=str(value)
    df_number=df.loc[df['number'] == str(value)]
    measures_name=dfnumber.numbername.unique()
    #below options for checklist(checkbox)
    options=[{'label':i, 'value':i} for i in measures_name]
    values=[]
    return html.Div([# dynamic tabs
        html.H5('Measurements'),
        dcc.Tabs(id="tabs-example", value='tab-1-example', children=[
            dcc.Tab(label='{}'.format(name), value='{}'.format(name)) for name in measures_name
        ])
    ]), options, number

@app.callback([Output('graph', 'figure')],
              [Input('tabs-example', 'value'),
              Input('memory-output', 'data')])
def render_graph(value,data):
    number=str(data)
    df_number=df.loc[df['number'] == str(number)]
    df_measures=df_number.loc[df_number['numbername'] == str(value)]
    numb=len(df_measures)+3
    x=list(range(0,numb))
    y=list(df_measures['number'])
    text_pin=df_measures['number'].tolist()
    text_meas=df_measures['numbervalue'].tolist()
    trace1=go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        mode='lines+markers+text',
        text=text_pin,
        textposition='top center',
        showlegend=False
    )
    trace21=go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        mode='lines+markers+text',
        text=text_meas,
        textposition='bottom center',
        showlegend=False
    )#lines
    figure={
        'data': [trace1,trace21],
        'layout':{
            'xaxis':{
                'showgrid':False,
                'zeroline':False,
                'showticklabels':False,
                },
            'yaxis':{
                'showgrid':False,
                'zeroline':False,
                'showticklabels':False,
            },
        }
    }
    return figure

@app.callback(Output('data-table', 'data'),
              [Input('tabs-example', 'value'),
              Input('memory-output', 'data')])
def render_table(val,dat):
    number=str(dat)
    df_number=df.loc[df['number'] == str(number)]
    df_measures=df_number.loc[df_number['numbername'] == str(val)]
    df_table=df_measures[['number']]
    data=df_table.to_dict('records')
    return data

@app.callback(Output('data-table', 'columns'),
              [Input('tabs-example', 'value')])
def fetch_columns(va):
    columns={'number':'one','number2':'two'}
    return columns


@app.callback(
    Output('checklist-graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('checklist', 'values'),
     Input('memory-output', 'data')])

def redner_checklist_graph(v,d):
    number=str(d)
    df_number=df.loc[df['number'] == str(number)]
    figure={
        'data': [go.Scatter
                 (
                     x= df_number[df_number['numbername']==str(vi)]['number'],
                     y= df_number[df_number['numbername']==str(vi)]['numbervalue'],
                     mode='lines+markers',
                     marker={
                          'size': 15,
                          'opacity': 0.5,
                     }
                 )
                 for vi in v]
        }
    return figure

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)





Are there any alternatives to pass the stored data(dcc.store) to all those callbacks?
```

Comment: Problem solved I used cookies to stores the data.